# Is flex's "align-items:flex-end" causing fixed-height divs inside flex-wrapped boxes to be vertically aligned according to each box's tallest one?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Doing a fairly basic HTML page I found myself perplexed by the following issue with flex in CSS.

First assume the following configuration:

- A div wrapper with `display: flex` and applying `justify-content: space-evenly`, containing three inner boxes (could be more or less) each one also using flex (applying `flex-wrap: wrap` and `align-items: end`).
- Each one of those inner boxes contains, in turn, two div elements: a top one and a bottom one (each with `width: 100%`); the bottom element has the same height while the top element has a different height per box; all of them are fixed heights in px.

This configuration looks more or less like this in HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="top-element one"></div>
    <div class="bottom-element one"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="top-element two"></div>
    <div class="bottom-element two"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="top-element three"></div>
    <div class="bottom-element three"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS (written in SCSS to save space, I will include a snippet below where you can check the compiled CSS should you prefer); the commented line: "align-content: flex-end" indicates that I've already evaluated the effect of this property.

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;

  .box {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    // align-content: flex-end;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 30%;

    .top-element {
      width: 100%;
      background-color: teal;

      &.one {
        height: 200px;
      }

      &.two {
        height: 300px;
      }

      &.three {
        height: 100px;
      }
    }

    .bottom-element {
      width: 100%;
      background-color: lightblue;

      &.one {
        height: 100px;
      }

      &.two {
        height: 100px;
      }

      &.three {
        height: 100px;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the snippet.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.wrapper .box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 30%;
}

.wrapper .box .top-element {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: teal;
}

.wrapper .box .top-element.one {
  height: 200px;
}

.wrapper .box .top-element.two {
  height: 300px;
}

.wrapper .box .top-element.three {
  height: 100px;
}

.wrapper .box .bottom-element {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.wrapper .box .bottom-element.one {
  height: 100px;
}

.wrapper .box .bottom-element.two {
  height: 100px;
}

.wrapper .box .bottom-element.three {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="top-element one"></div>
    <div class="bottom-element one"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="top-element two"></div>
    <div class="bottom-element two"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="top-element three"></div>
    <div class="bottom-element three"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*The issue is:* It doesn't matter if you change the height of any of the top elements on any inner box, these remain vertically center-aligned according to the tallest element among all boxes, while the bottom ones remain at the bottom, and the space between top and bottom elements on each box is proportionally kept.

*Now the question(s):* is this correct css? and if so, I'm suspicious of align-items:"end" on each box to be the one to blame for this result, am I right? and if I'm wrong, why does this happen then?

Why didn't I use grid? well I'm in my flex phase... bear with me please.

Comment: You _want_ those items in the `.box` elements below each other, but you did not actually use `flex-direction: column;` as you should have, but "emulated" that by adding `flex-wrap: wrap` to the default `flex-direction: row` ...

Comment: Yep, a missing direction column is what I read too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to define a vertical flex main direction for the elements with the CSS class `.box`.

Setting CSS property's [flex-direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction) value to `column` for those elements fixes your problem.

**SCSS**

```
.box {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you Bitski!, I guess I ended up hating "flex-direction:column" too much since it had some issues in IE11 and this was the hack I used to solve things quickly, but for what I see here apparently wrapping "flex-direction:row" boxes and giving inner elements "width 100%" to emulate columns is not right CSS.